# Get English Country Name from Country-Picklist

Tags: picklist, translation, country-and-state

we plan to enable the new Salesforce Country/State-Picklists.

we love the idea to have ISO Country-Codes but for a different system we need all the country-names in US-english spelling/name.

our org-default is german though and the country-picklist is only displayed in german, even if having enabled the english locale.

where/how can we retrieve the english country names specifically?
is there any apex-accessible table/object or something?

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the County names for England and the rest of the UK or the Countries for the UK?

Comment: i mean all the country-names in US-english spelling/name

Comment: Ok, I'm clear now - you will need all country names using US-English. Do you have multilanguage support enabled?

Comment: no idea, is this an actual setting?

Comment: Go to Setup>Company Profile>Language Settings and you can set several language settings there - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_getstart_what_languages_does.htm&type=0&language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions made in this answer**

1. State and Country/Territory Picklists have been enabled in Setup>Administer>Data Management and all values are converted
2. Translation Workbench has been setup for the languages with users selected for each supported language. [Translation Workbench documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workbench_overview.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.17)

**Setup of Translations**

Setup of Translation Workbench - got to Setup>Administer>Translation Workbench and enable this feature then setup translators.

[image]

Then setup the translations - unfortunately this will be a manual process as far as I can see, but is a one off activity as countries do not change their names frequently.

[image]

**Apex/SOQL settings**

To get the value in SOQL [documentation link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_tolabel.htm)

> Use toLabel() on regular, multi-select, division, or currency code picklist fields (any field that has picklist values returned by the relevant describe call), data category group and data category unique name fields or RecordType names. Any organization can use toLabel(). It is particularly useful for organizations that have the Translation Workbench enabled.

Comment: fun fact: `In 2013, the Cape Verdean government determined that the Portuguese designation "Cabo Verde" would henceforth be used for official purposes, such as at the United Nations, even in English contexts.` - thereby blowing up country picklists everywhere